# Can I host RavenDB inside my self-contained process?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ravendb

Is it possible to host RavenDB from within my own process? I do not want to use a separate IIS site or run a separate server .exe.

Looking for something pseudo-code like `RavenDB.Server.Start(8080)` (8080 being the port).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes...

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    DataDirectory = "Data",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};
```

See [this link](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded) for details.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.